# Attribute customization in RTC eclipse UI

Tags: eclipse, rtc

I am customizing work item in RTC.
When work item is created in summary attribute, there is a condition that work item shall be saved when summary contains minimum three words e.g "this is summary".
Is it possible to do with eclipse UI customization, without need to create plug in.

Comment: is it possible to achieve using script based attribute customization of any type for example, script base attribute customization for calculated values, default values. Or I will have to go for plug in

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way will be using [regular expression validator](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.workitem.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_configuring_regular_expression_validator.html).